# How to return the elements from a list which is a class attribute

Tags: c#, list

I have a problem, I am reading a xml file. After I am done and all the data is stored in the right data containers I am trying to access it.

Unfortunately I don't know how to access the elements in List cList; when I create an object of type CharSetTableMember

Below is the code for my class CharSetTableMember. Any help will be appreciated.

```
class CharSetTableMember
{
    int index;
    int count;
    List<char> cList;

    public CharSetTableMember(int indexIn, int countIn, List<char> cListIn)
    {
        index = indexIn;
        count = countIn;
        cList = cListIn;
    }


    public int getIndex()
    {
        return index;
    }
    public int getCount()
    {
        return count;
    }

    public List<char> getCharList()
    {
       return new List<char>(cList);
    }

}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Can you advise what XML you're reading, how you're reading it, and what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Well, you can get a _copy_ of the list via the `getCharList` method. What do you mean by "I don't know how to access the elements"?

Answer (score 0):

you said in question that you get all the data is stored in the right data containers.
so if you acieved object of CharSetTableMember then you can easily acccess its variable 
List cList; using this sample code.
suppose your object is like this.

```
     CharSetTableMember c ;//it has all the data you mentioned
    foreach(var item in c.cList)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
```